# Python Pandas, One hot encoding on 3000000 rows freezes computer and runs slowly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataset with around three million rows in it, with a mix of categorical and numerical data and I want to use Scikit learn's regression on the data.

Non-numeric data can't be put into a regression model so I am looking for the best way to encode the data this data.

I believe that One Hot Encoding is the best way to go and have come across two methods of doing this:

- The first using pandas built in function get_dummies

  ```
  setData = pd.get_dummies(s['is_self','media','agg_accounts_active', 'weekday', 'hour', 'submission_type', 'advertiser_category', 'lang'])
  ```
- The second using scikit learn's labelEncoder and oneHotEncoder

  ```
  X_int = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(labels.ravel()).reshape(*labels.shape)

  setData = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_int).toarray()
  ```

I prefer the pandas method as it deals with numerics itself. However I have run into efficiency problems, the get_dummies method freezes my computer when I try to use it on the three million rows.

Is there a better or more effecint way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the sparse matrices? Because after your `get_dummies()` most of the values will be zero.

Comment: I am not sure making it sparce helps. I saw someone saying that doing it in batches and writing it to a new database and working with it from there would help. What do you think?